# swift - Create new class for getting api with alamofire but can't dealing with async

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm a newly iOS developer and start to learn using alamofire.
here I can use alamofire to get data in my viewcontroller.swift.
but when I create a new class to write the same alamofire code , it won't get because of async.
 it'll return 0 first and the array prints up then.

how can I get array in ViewController after download finished?

in Viewcontroller:

```
self.jsonArray = Networking.alamofireGET("my_API")

    print(self.jsonArray.count)
```

in Networking class:

```
class Networking {

class func alamofireGET(url:String) -> NSMutableArray
{
    var orignalArray = NSMutableArray()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { response in

        if let JSON = response.result.value
        {
            //print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            orignalArray = JSON["data"] as! NSMutableArray
            print("抓到囉\(orignalArray)")

        }

    }

    return orignalArray
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

its unclear what you are trying to ask. If you want the array to load in view controller, you can simply add the code in the viewDidLoad() method of the VC. You can also use the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) method.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {//write code here what ever you want to do})
```

Comment: I mean that I get 0 in 'print(self.jsonArray.count)', but I've call 'self.jsonArray = Networking.alamofireGET("my_API")' first, It's should be counting right?

Comment: right, try using that code in the dispatch_async method, and then do it. It does not wait for the request to complete executing. You want to wait until it finishes executing the request. I ran into this issue few months ago when I started doing iOS development. Unfortunately I do not have the application anymore, but I remember fixing the issue using the dispatch_async method. Put the code in the {} of the snippet I have put above. That should make the app to wait for the request to finish. Hope this helps.